# Какой кроссплатформенный инструмент использовать для записи интерактивного видео?

Tags: android, c#, ios, xamarin

Нужно интерактивное видеоприложение, которое записывает и воспроизводит видео в видео. Мой план состоит в том, чтобы облачное приложение в будущем работало на всех платформах (веб-приложение, iOS, Android, Desktop). На данный момент мне нужна самая простая и самая быстрая платформа для сборки. Затем мы можем двигаться медленно на другие платформы. Я предпочитаю начинать с любого планшета или MS Surface, мы можем пойти в облако позже. Вот сейчас ищу способы реализации такой идеи, на чем можно написать такое приложение?

Answer (score 0):

Берите Xamarin.Native и реализуйте API для камер, со своим интерфейсом.
(Core проект с логикой будет написан один раз, потом будете реализовывать интерфейс для платформ и выпускать). Скорость работы приложения будет высокой.

В принципе не сложно, есть куча примеров, но надо знать, что к примеру Android имеет 2 API(старые и новые версии ОС).

Тут примеры как с этим работать
https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/android5.0/Camera2Raw/
https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/android5.0/Camera2Basic/

Пример "старого" кода для iOS (с 10 версии необходимо код слегка модифицировать, но принцип тот же).
https://blog.xamarin.com/how-to-display-camera-ios-avfoundation/

Готовых плагинов вряд ли найдете, обычно пишут свой, либо используют плагин для работы со стандартным интерфейсом.